# Django FileField.save() makes duplicate files

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

I have user submitted content that I am trying to write to a file and then save to a `FileField`.

so I have a *model* that looks like this:

```
class Revision(models.Model):
    def custom_revision_file_path(instance, filename):
        return '/'.join(['content/revisions', filename])
    path = models.FileField(upload_to=custom_revision_file_path)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
    ...
```

and the *view* that creates the instance looks like this:

```
def handle_revisions(request): 
    document = Document.objects.get(id=request.GET['docid'])
    basename = os.path.basename(str(document.path))

    revision = Revision.objects.create(
        document = document,
    )
    revision.path.save(basename, ContentFile(request.GET['revision']))
```

This all works relatively fine but for two problems:

1) the *ContentFile* puts a space between each letter in my string so `'test'` turns into `'t e s t'` ;

2) for some reason each time I run the view two `Revision` instances are saved with roughly the same path. ie. one path will be `'content/revisions/test.txt'` and the other will be `'content/revisions/test_1.txt'` when the second one shouldn't exist at all.

What gives?

Comment: For anyone coming to this question.  I've mostly moved on to a more elegant solution, but found that using http://chronosbox.org/blog/jsonresponse-in-django?lang=en was the source for duplicating my object instances.  Weird as I've used this module before... but it seems to not be working nicely here.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should never use something like that to create a path :

```
'/'.join(['content/revisions', filename])
```

but :

```
os.path.join("my_dir", "my_subdir", ..., "filename.txt")
```

You are not supposed to know if your application runs on *Unix-like* or on *Windows* (yes, some people use Windows as webserver).

Also, you should not call your `FileField` attribute `path`, this is ambiguous with `FilePathField`.

Is this field `NOT NULL` ? Because in your `create()` statement you don't provide one. This should raise an Error.

I don't get this :

```
revision.path.save(basename, ContentFile(request.GET['revision']))
```

What are you trying to achieve ? Are you sure you want to store a *GET* parameter in the file ?

To answer your question, by default, Django does not take the responsability to overwrite a file that exists on your filesystem, this is why it automatically store it with an [unique path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.save) by adding a suffix.

If this behaviour does not fits, consider writing a [custom file storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-file-storage/).

Comment: To be clear it's creating two instances of the class Revision both with their own files.  I guess I understand why ContentFile() would create a file and then `revision.path.save()` would create a file, but I don't see where it is making a second revision object.

Comment: Because if you call `MyModel.objects.create()` two times, you creates two entries in your database ! You need to use `get_or_create()` to retrieve or create a record. `ContentFile` does not create files (on the filesystem), this is more like a `StringIO`, in memory.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense but I still don't see it.  I call `Revision.objects.create()` once and call `instance.file_field.save()` once.  Any chance you could show me a working example or some sudo code? I don't see where or why I would use `get_or_create`. See http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_frm/thread/184e5e09db1efce4/7816cbc650d8dc77 for the basic reference I'm working from.